# Decode/encode base64 string to get nodes of a graph

Tags: javascript, jquery, base64, decode, encode

I'm trying to create a small tool for a computer game, where one function is to paste an url and decode it's nodes from a graph, that are base64 encoded.

Here is an example:

Root (ID: 54447): 
https://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree/AAAAAwMA

Root with some active nodes in graph:
https://www.pathofexile.com/passive-skill-tree/AAAAAwMAGyVLrm0Z2VvfiukC

Outcome must be [54447, 57226, 59650, 19374, 6949, 55643, 27929], I don't know if its ordered, but this are the node IDs, that are active. Maybe the root ID isn't even in that array (see code below).

You can also test it at the official site, just click on some nodes, the url will change.
After some research I've found following code, but can not get it to work:

```
url = url.replace(/\-/g, "+").replace(/\_/g, "/"); // also delete the part before the base64 string

// get nodes
var a = [];
        for (i = 6; i < url.length; i += 2) {
            var o = (255 & url[i]) << 8 | 255 & url[i + 1];
            a.push(o);
        }

// get root
var d = ((255 & url[0]) << 24 | (255 & url[1]) << 16 | (255 & url[2]) << 8 | (255 & url[3]) << 0, url[4]);
```

I don't know what I have to do with the string, do I have to convert it to binary data or something like that, to work with the code above?

Can someone please help me to figure out, how I can decode/encode this strings?
I've never done something with base64, so I'm really lost.

Thank you.

Comment: If you are doing anything with base64 in JS, just go for the [`atob`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/atob) and [`btoa`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowBase64/btoa) `window` methods. Don't write the algorithm yourself.

Comment: I've tested this already, did't work in this case :(

Comment: Why not? What did you get?

Comment: atob('AAAAAwMAGyVLrm0Z2VvfiukC') = some strange chars.

Comment: `atob("AAAAAwMAGyVLrm0ZksHZW9-K37DpAg==".replace(/-/g, "+").replace(/_/g, "/"))` *is* what you want. Yes, those are strange chars. Get their char codes and convert them to integers like they do it.